# In Azure Devops or TFS is it possible to pass a PowerShell argument that is variable on the pipeline environment?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am trying to create a Task Group that can be used interchangeably between Build and Release pipelines.

However, I am having an issue passing one of the arguments to my Powershell Task Group.

The reason for this is that the argument data that I'm trying to pass doesn't exist within the Build environment.

```
- envName "$(Release.EnvironmentName)"
```

For example, can I setup logic to send a different variable if this Task Group is executed within the Build environment?

Is there a way for me to pass this argument only if it exists? Or to pass this argument OR a different argument?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to pass argument that exist only in the Release?

Comment: I am trying to build a Task Group that can be used interchangeably between Build & Release... and the built-in functionality I'm keying off of exist in Build, but not Release... and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Azure Devops or TFS is it possible to pass a PowerShell argument that is variable on the pipeline environment?

I am afraid there is no such way that we could pass a PowerShell argument that is variable on the pipeline environment **directly**.

But as a workaround, you can add a another powershell task in your Powershell Task Group to set the variable based on the pipeline environment, like:

```
Write-Host "Current Release Name is $Env:Release_EnvironmentName"

$ReleaseName= $Env:Release_EnvironmentName

Write-Host "Current Environment Release Name is $ReleaseName"

if ($ReleaseName-eq "")
{
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=envName]TestValue1")
}
else
{
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=envName]TestValue2")
}
```

The `envName` will be set different value based on the value of the `$Env:Release_EnvironmentName`, we could use it in the next Powershell Task in the Powershell Task Group.

Check the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) during the build/release for some more details.

Hope this helps.